# How do I connect to Windows Virtual Server on the IBM Cloud

Tags: windows-server, ibm-server

I am trying to connect to a Windows Virtual Server on the IBM Cloud.

I have this document,

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vsi-is?topic=virtual-servers-is-connecting-to-your-windows-instance

But currently

```
ibmcloud **is** instance-status <instance id>
```

Isn't working saying that "is" isn't a supported command

*'is' is not a registered command. See 'ibmcloud help'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the infrastructure plugin...

```
 ibmcloud plugin install infrastructure-service
```